# reading, writing, appending, and deleting files in python

Tags: python, ubuntu

here's my code, i could use your help.

My program is supposed to accept data input, create new text files,read and write into text files, append text into already existing text files, truncate and delete files.
Now the problem i have with my program is that the the part of the code that is supposed to append text, truncate the content of a text file and delete a text file is not working and the program does not return any errors during run time.

```
import os
from sys import argv

filename = argv

def menu():
    holder = input("enter 1 to create new file or 2 to use existing ones\n")
    if holder == 1:
        dam = raw_input("Enter name of new text file:\n")+'.txt'
        textfile = open(dam, 'w+')
        happ = raw_input("\nPlease enter record into your new file\n\n")
        textfile.write(happ)
        textfile.close()
        print "*******************"
        print "*******************\n"

        print "To view the content of your new file, enter 'yes' otherwise enter 'no' to exit"

        gett = raw_input()

        if gett == 'yes':

            print "*******************"
            print "\nyour inputted record is>>>\n"
            display = open(dam)
            print(display.read())
            print'\n'
            menu()
        elif gett == 'no':
            print ("\nOk, see you later. Have a nice day!")
            print'\n'
            menu()
        else:
            print "\nyou have entered a wrong input"
            print '\n'
            menu()
   elif holder == 2:
       filename = raw_input("Enter name of file:\n")+'.txt'
       entry = raw_input("Press 7 to append text into this file, 8 to truncate the content of this file, or 9 to delete this file : ")
       if entry == 7:
           print ("Displayed below is the content of your file, continue to append more text at the bottom of the file.(text is limited to 3 lines)\n")
           textfiles = open(filename, 'a+')
           print (textfiles.read())
           line1 = raw_input( )
           line2 = raw_input( )
           line3 = raw_input( )
           print "\nSaving..."
           textfiles.write(line1)
           textfiles.write('\n')
           textfiles.write(line2)
           textfiles.write('\n')
           textfiles.write(line3)
           textfiles.write('\n')
           print "\nSaved!"
           textfiles.close()
       elif entry == 8:
           textfiles = open(filename, 'w')
           print "Truncating the file..."
           textfiles.truncate()
           print "Done, truncated."
           textfiles.close()
           right = raw_input("Do you want to write into this file? Y/N : ")
           if right == 'Y':
               textfiles = open(filename, 'a+')
               print "text is limited to 3 lines"
               line1 = raw_input('\n')
               line2 = raw_input()
               line3 = raw_input()
               print "\nSaving..."
               textfiles.write(line1)
               textfiles.write('\n')
               textfiles.write(line2)
               textfiles.write('\n')
               textfiles.write(line3)
               textfiles.write('\n')
               print "\nSaved!"
               textfiles.close()
           else:
               print "Ok have a nice day"
       elif entry == 9:
            print "Deleting the file..."
            try:
                os.remove(filename)
            except OSError, e:  #if failed, report it back to the user
                print ("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))
                print "Done, deleted."
       else:
           print "Error! wrong entry"
           print '\n'
           menu()
    else:
        print "\nyou have entered a wrong input"
        print '\n'
        menu()
menu()
```

This is the output it gives

enter 1 to create new file or 2 to use existing ones

2

Enter name of file:

test

Press 7 to append text into this file, 8 to truncate the content of this file, or 9 to delete this file : 8

Error! wrong entry

enter 1 to create new file or 2 to use existing ones

ANY HELP ON HOW TO MAKE THIS WORK?

Comment: You need to convert `entry` to an `int` before your conditionals, otherwise the comparisons will never pass. Alternatively, if your conditionals were something like `if entry == '7':`, that would also work.

Comment: sys and argv are not needed. If you really want to read the filename from the argument list, you would need to use: `filename = argv[1]`. See: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html

Comment: thanks  JCVanHamme, but it work in the case of holder, why then can't it work for entry?

Comment: Ashafix your comment was helpful...Thanks

Comment: @ebi For security reasons, it's best to not use `input()` in python 2.7. It evaluates the input; i.e. it essentially does `eval(raw_input())` meaning that you can write code that would get executed via `input()` (try writing `5-4` when your script asks for input and it would evaluate to 1 and enter `if holder == 1:`) . Best to use `int(raw_input())`. In Python 3.x, `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` and Python 2.x's `input()` was removed so it's not an issue in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function `raw_input()` for your variable `entry` at the line

```
entry = raw_input("Press 7 to append text into this file, 8 to truncate the content of this file, or 9 to delete this file : ")
```

Refering to the documentation of `python2` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), the function `raw_input` return a `String`.

After, you are testing your variable `entry` against `integer` values. Since a `String` never equals an `int`, the test won't work. And your code fall in the last condition block which is "wrong input"

To fix this issue, you should use the `input` function like you did at the begining of your code (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

```
entry = input("Press 7 to append text into this file, 8 to truncate the content of this file, or 9 to delete this file : ")
```

or cast `entry` to `int`

```
entry = int(raw_input("Press 7 to append text into this file, 8 to truncate the content of this file, or 9 to delete this file : "))
```